# How can I assign vim to be the default application to open my _vimrc file? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, vim, vimrc, file-association

I would like to be able to double click on the file "_vimrc" and have it open up in vim.

However, "_vimrc" doesn't have a file extension so I can't have it open in vim based on file type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. This is really the wrong approach here. You usually open up _vimrc only from vim (and usually source it right afterwards), therefore no need for an association.

Just put this in your _vimrc:

```
let mapleader = ","
nmap <leader>v :e $myvimrc
nmap <leader>s :so $myvimrc
```

and when you need a quick setting made, you *,v* - do it, then write it *:w*, and source it *,s*. (these are my mappings, you're free to change them to your liking).

Answer (score 1):

I found an [article](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/67/1/How-to-associate-Notepad-to-open-files-with-no-extension.html) that describes how to associate **all** extensionless files with a given application. Not exactly what I wanted, but it may do for now. It works. I tried it.

Comment: Finally, you got it right! Works fine for me too! Thanks for the info. You deserve 10 points :) Well, 20 since I upvote your question.

Comment: @r0ca. Thanks for the support. However, I'm not satisfied with my own answer. It's just a workaround. I don't really want to affect all extensionless files, just one. I would be glad to see an answer that would show me how to do this.

Answer (score -2):

When you want to open your file, right-click on it and hit: **Open with**... Then, hit: **Choose default program**.

Then, select your VIM application and you will see "**Always use the selected program to open this kind of file"**

It should work!

Comment: How do you get `Open with...` to come up when there is no file extension?

Comment: Then right-click on it, hit OPEN. Then you'll be prompt to chose the program to open it. Then select "Select a program from a list of installed programs". Then, select the program you want and check at the bottom: "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file".

Comment: The "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" option is greyed out so that I cannot select it. Try creating a file that doesn't have an extension to try it out.

Comment: I tried it and it worked fine for me. Are you local admin?

Comment: I tried logging off my standard user account and then logging in as the super user and that did not make a difference. It sounds like you have the setting "hide known file extensions" enabled.

Comment: I don't have it checked so I can see extensions and modify them. I also have Windows 7 Ultimate Edition

Comment: I am using Windows 7 Enterprise Edition, which is basically the same thing.